# Kafka Timeout exception while requesting metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Intermittently we recieve this exception when its trying to send a MESSAGE to a topic.
Kafka version: 0.10.0.1

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for topic-89
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:65) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1-cp1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:52) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1-cp1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1-cp1.jar:?]
```

Initial investigation shows that whenever we recieve this excption, it seems to only last 24 hours and then it resolves itself without having to restart the cluster or doing anything.

Another thing is that this only happens on a CERTAIN topics and not all topics.